# Backreference in Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, backreference, capturing-group

So, I have a JavaScript regexp like this:

```
/url:.?(['"])(https?:\/\/.*?)\1/
```

I use it to find specific url inside html/js code. As you can see I capture link inside either `''` or `""`. 
This is a problem, because I don't want to get links like 'http://'.

```
/url:.?(['"])(https?:\/\/.+)\1/
```

This also picks stuff like 'http://"+d+', also bad.

I'd like to be able to say in the regex something like this:

```
/(['"])(https?:\/\/[^\1]+)\1/
```

To use [^\1] instead of a dot, to only get whatever is inside '' or "", making sure it does not pick up 'http://"+d+'

Is there a way to do stuff like this?

Comment: are you saying you want to match for the url inside the quotes, but only if it is a valid url format?

Comment: As neither apostrophe `'` nor quote character `"` are valid in an URL (among other characters), you can just use `[^"']` (simplified). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547899/which-characters-make-a-url-invalid for all allowed characters.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are actually trying to accomplish, but to answer your question about equivalent of `[^\1]+`, you can do this: `(['"])((?:(?!\1).)+)`

Comment: I feel you actually do not need the backreference, just use the negated character class - [`/(['"])(https?:\/\/[^'"]+)\1/`](https://regex101.com/r/Z10mGg/2).

Comment: Is this in the browser and you are searching through the InnerHTML of something?

Comment: Hey, yes this is code intended for the browser, which first goes through my node.js app first. 
I am trying to find valid urls, however I decode them from the strict URL format and so it can actually have ' or " inside, as part of query string.

Comment: The [`(['"])((?:(?!\1).)+)`](https://regex101.com/r/q5wed4/1) does not seem to be what is necessary here.

Comment: @AlexL.: Any feedback? Did my comment help?

Comment: Hey, no, not really. It was all helpful, but apparently this specific case is not possible in plain regex. Gone with [^'"].

Comment: @AlexL. I see, but see my answer below now. It actually resolves the issue you stated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `[^\1]` matches any char but a `\x01` char (SOH, start of heading). That is because inside character classes, `\` + digit cannot define a backreference. See [ECMAScript reference](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.2.19):

> Inside a *CharacterClass*, `\b` means the backspace character, while `\B` and backreferences raise errors.

Actually, in JS implementation, as you see, `\1` inside the `[...]` class forms an octal escape (see [Using special characters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_special_characters)).

In your case, you just want to match any char but `'` and `"` with `[^'"]`, you do not need to check for  the previously matched qualifier:

```
/(['"])(https?:\/\/[^'"]+)\1/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z10mGg/2)

**Details**

- `(['"])` - Group 1: a `'` or `"`
- `(https?:\/\/[^'"]+)` - Group 2: `http`, an optional `s`, `://`, 1 or more chars other than `'` and `"`
- `\1` - the value of Group 1.